# How to run Tampermonkey script if page fails to load?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have a script which runs on pages of a server that sometimes sends doesn't send anything back to the clients (I get the *No data received* error in Chrome). I want to register this event (notify another server via AJAX) and then reload the page.

How can I make sure my script runs even if the page fails to load?

Comment: Can't do it. The page errors out before document-start -- which is the earliest that a Tampermonkey script can run. If this is for page monitoring, don't try to use a userscript for that. If for something else, state your true purpose or just hit reload on the offending page.

Comment: This is exactly what I need - a script that periodically fills in some forms and sends me an email when a page load fails (I have a server script for that). But if the load fails, it shouldn't reload. So I just asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/23724668/492130 in case you know the answer.

Comment: @f.ardelian perhaps you should have a server-side script, not a userscript, to do that. Never trust the client environment (to even exist).

Comment: You may check connectivity using Ajax from a different domain (a domain that never fails). I think GM_xmlhttpRequest() would do.